# Spring 3.x - Bean named 'zoneManagerDelegate' must be of type [com.ms.adsp.delegate.sapi.ZoneManagerDelegate], but was actually of type [$Proxy20]

Tags: java, spring

I have huge complex Spring project. When i added new class:

```java
@Service("zoneManagerDelegate")  
@Cached(keyGeneratorClass=ServiceGlobalKeyGenerator.class,dataWrapperClass=ServiceDelegateDataWrapper.class, tags = {"service", "sapi"})  
public class ZoneManagerDelegate extends SapiDelegate<ZoneManagerWS> {

    public ZoneManagerDelegate(){
        super(ZoneManagerWS.class);
    }

    @Cached
    public Object[] getZones(SalesUserContext userContext) throws SalesAPIException {
        return getWs().getZones(userContext);
    }
}
```

and run project, I encountered an error output:

```java
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'conversionService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/common.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rtChargeEntryDetailsToBookedInsertionInfo' while setting bean property 'converters' with key [14]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rtChargeEntryDetailsToBookedInsertionInfo': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ms.adsp.objectFinder.ObjectFinderService com.ms.adsp.bean.payment.converter.RtChargeEntryDetailsToBookedInsertionInfo.objectFinderService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectFinderService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.ms.adsp.objectFinder.ObjectFinderService.setObjectFinderExts(java.util.Collection); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectFinderExtFactory': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'zoneManagerDelegate' must be of type [com.ms.adsp.delegate.sapi.ZoneManagerDelegate], but was actually of type [$Proxy20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedSet(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:158)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Usage looks something like this:

```
@Component  
public class ObjectFinderExtFactory {

    @Resource(name="zoneManagerDelegate")
    private ZoneManagerDelegate zoneManagerDelegate;

...
```

}

When i remove @Cached annotation in ZoneManagerDelegate - it's working fine. All other delegates that extends SapiDelegate - work fine too.

Additional information:

```java
public abstract class SapiDelegate<T> implements ApplicationListener<EnvironmentReloaded> {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SapiDelegate.class);

private T wsInstance;

private final Class<T> wsClass;

public SapiDelegate(Class<T> wsClass){
    this.wsClass = wsClass;
}

@Override
public synchronized void onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentReloaded appReloaded) {
    wsInstance = null;
    logger.debug("Sales API client invalidated: " + wsClass.getName());
}

/**
 * Returns webservice client object
 */
protected synchronized  T getWs() {
    try {
        if (wsInstance == null) {
            wsInstance = ClientFactory.createClient(wsClass, "adsalespro");
            logger.debug("Sales API client created: " + wsClass.getName());
        }
        return (T) wsInstance;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SapiException(e);
    }
}
```

}

version:
Spring 3.2.0
apache-tomcat-6.0.36

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give the fully qualified name of the @Cached class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me it seems that problem lays in that you are not programming against **INTERFACES**.

try to define interface like this:

```
public interface ZoneManagerDelegateInterface  {

    public Object[] getZones(SalesUserContext userContext) throws SalesAPIException
}
```

and implement it with your `ZoneManagerDelegate`.
Then use it referring to it's interface:

```
@Component  
public class ObjectFinderExtFactory {

    @Resource(name="zoneManagerDelegate")
    private ZoneManagerDelegateInterface zoneManagerDelegate;

...
```

**UPDATE**

Another solution is using **CGLIB** proxies instead of **JDK dynamic proxies**. This can be forced in [Spring configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying). Note that you need CGLIB on your classpath (not true since Spring 3.2.0).

Here is interesting [comparison of CGLIB proxies and JDK Dynamic proxies](http://insufficientinformation.blogspot.cz/2007/12/spring-dynamic-proxies-vs-cglib-proxies.html)

Comment: Thx, <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/> working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you use annotation-driven application context, annotate your @Configuration class with

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

You also have to add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
<version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well implementing the interface in my class solved the problem.

```
public interface UserInterface  {
    public void saveDetails();
}
```

Implement the above interface in the class you are going to use it,

```
public class UserInterfaceImpl implements UserInterface{
  //your implementation stuff goes here
}
```